# Retrieve X, Y coords from nested Lua table

Tags: lua

I need to get the values from a nested table in Lua, I just cannot figure out how to do it, I have tried numerous online examples but none work.

Any help would be appreciated

table

```
xy = { a={x=0,y=0},b={x=0,y=100}, c={x=0,y=200}}
```

if unpack(route) contains a and c, how can I get the x,y values from the table above.

I have tried

```
for _, v in pairs(xy) do
  print(v[1], v[2])
end
```

But all i get back is nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using arrays, therefore neither unpack nor numerical indexing is going to help you. Instead you can use syntactic sugar:

```
print(xy.a.x, xy.a.y)
```

If you wish to loop over them all:

```
for i,v in pairs(xy) do
    print(i..": "v.x, v.y)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `pairs` give you `key, value` pair, the `value` part is the table with `x` and `y` values; now you can simply do:

```
print(v.x, v.y)
```

Using `v[1]` and `v[2]` retrieves first and second element of that table, but these are *not* `x` and `y` elements, so that's why you get `nil` in your case.

In general, nested tables are accessed in the same way: `t.index1.index2`, etc. If indexes are numeric, then you need to use `t[1][2]` notation, which means: get the second element of the table retrieved as the first element of table `t`.